# Pass data to register view - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to pass an array in the register view (using php artisan make:auth in laravel 5.3) but I can't find where I can do it properly.

Here the code in my view :

```
{{ Form::select('promo_id', $promos, old('promo_id'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required')) }}
```

Promo is a model and I would like to get promos into the $promos variable for the view.

**EDIT :**

Here the method in my controller for getting promos :

```
public function getPromos()
{
    $promos = Promo::orderBy('nom', 'asc')->get();
    return $promos;

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code in your controller where you generate `$promos`?

Comment: added ! it's just a get method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to pass `$promos` to view:

```
   public function getPromos()
    {
        $promos = Promo::orderBy('nom', 'asc')->get();
        return view('register')->with(['promos'=>$promos]);

    }
```